# how would i go about looping through a sqlite table and displaying the data on a html page run by flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to display the name field of all records from the eventdetails table onto a the home.html page. models.py is connected to home.html via **init**.py 
Currently, only the Header is displayed on the homepage

home.html

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}
    {% block content %}

    <h1 align="center">Club/Event List</h1>
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="clubEventList">
      {% for person in EventDetails %}
      <li class="list-group-item">
        {{ person.name }}
      </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
 
    {% endblock %}
```

only the header is displayed

EventDetails is part of models.py

```
    class EventDetails(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = db.Column(db.String(30))
        maxSpaces = db.Column(db.Integer)
        date = db.Column(db.Date)
        time = db.Column(db.Time)
        location = db.Column(db.String(50))
        yearGroup = db.Column(db.String(50))
        weekday = db.Column(db.Integer)
        clubOrEvent = db.Column(db.String(5))
        description = db.Column(db.String(300))
        organiser_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

[table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvHMG.png)
**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from os import path
from flask_login import LoginManager

db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = "database.db"

def create_database(app):
    if not path.exists('webs/'+DB_NAME):
        db.create_all(app=app)
        print('Database Created!')

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'drowssap'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
    db.init_app(app)

    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth

    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')
    
    from .models import User, EventDetails
    
    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = 'views.home'
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(id):
        return User.query.get(int(id))

    create_database(app)

    return app

def create_database(app):
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
```

views.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
from flask_login import current_user

views = Blueprint('views', __name__)

#defining homepage to be home.html

@views.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    return render_template("home.html", user=current_user)
```

Comment: Please post code, never images of code. Next, if only the heading renders, `eventdetails` is empty. The jinja template syntax appears correct. Check the value you're passing for it to the template.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: event details definitely is not empty, and EventDetails was imported as EventDetails - Is the for statement incorrect?

Comment: The `for` syntax is correct. I verified by passing `eventdetails=[{'name': 'foo'}, {'name': 'bar'}]` as an argument to `render()` and it generated the list items. Print the value you're passing as `eventdetails` to the template in order to verify its structure. It would be helpful to put the code which renders the template in the question.

Comment: Where is the view which renders the template?

Comment: attached the views.py for my homepage now

Comment: The template, home.html, requires a variable named `EventDetails` (`eventdetails` before the edit) but the view isn't providing it. The view provides only `user`. As the code is presented, `EventDetails = None` in the template context. The view must pass an `iterable` of objects which have the member: `name`, and it should be the kwarg `EventDetails`. Renaming the template variable from `eventdetails` to `EventDetails` doesn't automagically query the db for the data and inject it into the template.

Comment: Thanks a lot, code works now :)
this is my first flask project, you're a saviour

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Keep with it. Flask is a [microframework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microframework) and provides flexibility in lieu of automation. Generally, it expects _explicit_ instruction. On the other hand, a full-stack framework typically relies on naming conventions in order to provide _implicit_ instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `EventDetails` to `render_template` to provide a list of all `EventDetails` to home.html and render a list of names:

```py
@views.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    return render_template(
        "home.html",
        user=current_user,
        EventDetails=EventDetails.query.all()
    )
```